# best way to multi-language asp.net mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, multilingual, performance

I'm trying to create a asp.net mvc3 project for a academic project, and one of the requirements is it has to be able to change between different languages. Currently what i have is the following:

I have a external project that works as a repository for languages and for each view i have an interface for each view that defines all the "placeholders" do define all the changeable text.
At the beginning of any action i obtain the language that is in the uri (something like /{lng}/{command}/{action}) and pass it to the view using the ViewBag, once inside the view i user the repository to obtain the current implementation of the interface for that view in the chosen language.

I can't find any good topic on this mater. I'm just curios if there is a better way to do this and more efficient. And how is it normally done in a professional level.
I'm not very experienced with asp.net just started learning it about a month ago.

Also if it's important i am using the razor engine for the views, and we can't use any JavaScript in this phase of the project.

Comment: try this [Multi Language Website In MVC 4 C#](http://lesson8.blogspot.in/2013/03/multi-language-website-in-mvc-4-c.html)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may go through the [following guide](http://adamyan.blogspot.com/2010/02/aspnet-mvc-2-localization-complete.html).

Comment: just a question does this work fine with the razor view engine or is it more designed for aspx.

Answer (score 2):

I'm working with a project called Griffin.MvcContrib which has some localization features.

First of all, I use the query string and a cookie to switch language. (Just create a link with a flag in your layout `<a href="@Url.Action("Index")?lang=en-us">English</a>`)

and tag your controller with my attribute:

```
[LocalizedAttribute]
public class YourController : Controller
{

}
```

The next thing is to get localization of views, models and validation messages. 
The localization of models and validations are [described here](http://blog.gauffin.org/2011/09/easy-model-and-validation-localization-in-asp-net-mvc3/). As for views, you only need to use `@T()` to get translated texts:

```
@Model.Title

<div>@T("This text will get translated")</div>
```

(you need to change pageBaseType in Views\Web.config to `Griffin.MvcContrib.GriffinWebViewPage`)

I'm almost done with an adminstration area that any non-technical user can use to manage all translations. Check the `Griffin.MvcContrib.Admin`  project here: https://github.com/jgauffin/griffin.mvccontrib/tree/localization/source/Griffin.MvcContrib.Admin

Comment: This project looks really awesome, and i'd love to use it, but as of being  an academic project we are restricted to only using what we have and can make with asp.net mvc 3. But thank you very much

Comment: Then read about the poor mans approach here: http://blog.gauffin.org/2010/11/simplified-localization-for-dataannotations/